# Docker image build error : no space left on device

Tags: docker, centos, dockerfile, overlay, docker-machine

I am trying to build a docker image in which i need to copy a DB dump of size around 170GB.
When i run command

```
docker build -t imagename:tag .
```

I am getting error message in the image build step in which dump is copied.

**No space left on device**

Although i have around 500 GB disk space free. I am not sure why i am facing this error. Do we have any image size limits in docker or overlay2. I am using CentOS machine and the storage driver is overlay2 .

Comment: In my past experience, I've hit operational trouble when single layers get up around 1 GB.  Without seeing the Dockerfile, I'm guessing you'll need at least 3 copies of the file to build it (1 on the host system, 1 in Docker temporary space to copy the build context, 1 actually in the image).

Comment: @DavidMaze I have used the same Dockerfile to create other db images from different docker build context only difference there was another db dump of size around 6GB. In that case image builing worked fine. But in case when the db dump size is 170GB image building is failing even though space is left on my device. Do we have some docker image size limits which are hitting?